# WebAPI Token Issuance Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am currently using Sessions and overriding the AuthorizeAttribute to manage Authorization for a WebAPI endpoint, which is used by an MVC Web Application.  I've been told issuing tokens is the best way to manage users and roles.  What I'm trying to understand is:

1. Why is it better than using the Session?
2. Can someone provide a good (simple) example of how to issue tokens, when a user logs in using a WebAPI endpoint, and how to use/track the token after it has been issued.

I've been researching OWIN and a bunch of other stuff and I'm having a difficult time finding a good example of how this works.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication) is very good.  Essentially, tokens 'go along' with the stateless nature of the web.

Comment: @Jonesopolis - Thanks.  Do you know where I can find some sample code specific to WebAPI?

Comment: [BitOfTech](http://bitoftech.net/) is a good resource I use.  He has a lot of WebAPI token authentication examples.  Most of it is tied into AngularJS, but you can pick out just the server-side aspects.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Nice.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sure thing, all credit to @TaiseerJoudeh of course

Comment: I worked on it by following [these](http://bitoftech.net/) good tutorials. However as your first question concerns, a session less application can be hosted a void group of servers to face huge number of trafic.

Comment: An excelent getting started is the one from IdentityServer3. It walks through setting up your own STS, but in the meantime it also shows you the code how to work with claims and tokens in your MVC and WebAPI solutions. See https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

Comment: @Niels Awesome thank you.

Comment: @Mr.B your best bet is IdentityServer3. Were are using it in our company to issue authorization and identity tokens. And to support different OAuth flows. Is not easy the start up, but is very complete solution https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tokens are more secure and built into ASP.Net Identity framework. No need to roll your own solution.
2. Look at sections "Get an Access Token" and "Send an Authenticated Request" from this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api. The endpoint is already setup in the default MVC template. You can also use PostMan to test.