# External Owin Authentication without cookies or Local credentials

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I am working on a cross platform web app using angular and webapi. The problem is when the angular app runs in a cordova container. To play nice with the rest of the applications on the device, I am required to use a plugin for SSO.. This plugin is what is causing me issues, because it does a few things. It intercepts all the http requests and adds a bearer token to the header, which is generated by a 3rd party Token provider, so I can't decode it, and overwrites any bearer token I have set in the header.It also seems to block cookies..

So it makes it a bit tricky when you can't send you own local credentials.

So I started with https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/ and http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.cs

So I figured I should write my own middleware to take care of this; I thought since the standard oauth middleware can work without cookies, I should not have too hard a time getting my slightly different bearer token middleware to do it.. But that has not been the case... Writing my own middleware.. so I'm able to get the header, validate with the external token provider, but I can't actually sign in.

```
   protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Find token in default location
                string requestToken = null;
                string authorization = Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
                {
                    if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        requestToken = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    }
                }
.... Take the Request token call other Server, verify token...
```

Also

```
    public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
         var ticket = await this.AuthenticateAsync();
         if(ticket != null)
         {
           this.Context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(), grantIdentity);
           return false;
         }
    }
```

So in the end the SignIn does not cause a error or anything, but does not actually signin. As soon as I get to a controller action with an [Authorize] attribute, I get a 401. I  not have any external cookies enabled. There is a high probability that I am on the wrong track or I am making it way too hard.

Comment: I have found it simpler to just override the authorize attribute.  I asked a similar question, and this guy gave me the following link (BitOfTech.net).  Please post if you get this figured out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099027/webapi-token-issuance-authorization)

Comment: @Mr.B - Hey check out my answer.. I was finally able to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So… I ment to answer it earlier, but I was able to figure it out, without override the authorize attribute. I ended up looking at the source for the OWIN security code. The trick is, you really need 2 OWIN middleware components. One is the what I call (and I stole this from the owin source) the server middleware. The server middleware responds to the challenge and/or if you are feeling crazy generate local credentials for you. This middleware is also a PASSIVE middleware component. I won’t get in to generating the local credentials unless someone asks , because it’s a bit off point, but if someone thinks it will be helpful, I can update.

```
public class LowCalorieAuthenticationServerHandler : AuthenticationHandler<LowCalorieAuthenticationServerOptions>
{
    //Important this needs to be overriden, but just calls the base. 
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>The apply response challenge async.</summary>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
    protected override async Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
    {
        if (this.Response.StatusCode != 401)
        {
            Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            return;
        }

        var challenge = this.Helper.LookupChallenge(
            this.Options.AuthenticationType,
            this.Options.AuthenticationMode);
        if (challenge != null)
        {
            //OK in here you call the rediret to the 3rd party 
            //return a redirect to some endpoint
        }
        Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        return;
    }
}
```

Anyway notice how the override AuthenticateCoreAsync() just returns 
    return Task.FromResult(null);
This is because we don’t want this middleware to modify the request. ApplyResponseChallengeAsync will wait for a Challenge and redirect you to the 3rd party login. IF you want to create a local token of some sort you would override the InvokeAsync method

The second middle ware you need is the token/external credentials validator. This will then authenticate the user somehow. In the case of the local bearer token that is built into the OWIN security, it simple deserializes the token and if it can, and the token is not expired it authenticates the user. So in the case that you want to verify the token with a 3rd part sso, such as google or anything, you insert you logic here. In my case I not only wanted to call the 3rd party provider to get the user info, but to check if they token was still valid for single sign out, and to prevent multiple sessions.

```
public class LowCalorieAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<LowCalorieAuthenticationOptions>
{

    //Going to give you the user for the request.. You Need to do 3 things here
    //1. Get the user claim from teh request somehow, either froma header, request string, or cookie what ever you want
    //2. validate the user with whatever user store or 3rd party SSO you want
    //3. Generate a AuthenticationTicket to send to on to the request, you can use that to see if the user is valid in any Identity collection you want.  
    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {




        //Good to throw in a point of override here.. but to keep it simple-ish
        string requestToken = null;
        string authorization = Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");

        //TOTAL FAKEOUT.. I am going to add a bearer token just so the simple sample works, but your client would have to provide this
        authorization = "Bearer  1234567869";

        //STEP 1 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            requestToken = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
            return await FakeExternalBearer(requestToken);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> FakeExternalBearer(string token)
    {
        var authenticationType = Options.AuthenticationType;
        //pretend to call extenal Resource server to get user //STEP 2
        //CallExternal(token)

        //Create the AuthTicket from the return.. I will fake it out
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            authenticationType,
                            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
                            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"user1", null, authenticationType));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Jon",null, authenticationType));

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
        properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
        properties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var ticket =  new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        return ticket;
    }
}
```

Ok here we override AuthenticateCoreAsync, but we actually do something now. This this were your do you user authentication. This is the ACTIVE part of the middleware. Note it needs to return a valid AuthenticationTicket. This will run on each request so be careful what you call and how often. 
So I have a very simple example here https://github.com/jzoss/LowCalorieOwin If anyone is interested in more detail, please ask. I can add more. I did make it too hard, because now that I understand it, it’s pretty easy, but there is really no good examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it way too hard.

Instead of creating your own bearer authentication middleware you should change the default `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`.

Here is a sample for sending the token in the query string.

```
//in Startup class
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider(),
    //your settings
});

//implementation
public class QueryStringOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    private const string AccessTokenQueryKey = "access_token";

    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        //check if token found in the default location - "Authorization: Bearer <token>" header
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
        {
            var token = context.Request.Query.Get(AccessTokenQueryKey);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                context.Token = token;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```